# I am trying to understand this standalone method for practice

Tags: ruby

Im trying to write a standalone method named count_lines that returns the number of lines in an input string.
If i run this test code it should produce the output shown:

```
s = %W/This
is
a
test./
print "Number of lines: ", count_lines(s), "\n"
# Output:
Number of lines: 4
```

I am fairly new to Ruby and I am trying to figure out if this pseudocode of the actual output or not. Please help me!!

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: I am trying to figure out if this is pseudocode or actual ruby code. I am getting undefined 'count_line' for main:Object (NoMethodError) when I test it out.

Comment: It is actual ruby code but the definition of the `count_lines` method is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume `count_lines` is a method that counts the number of elements in a an array, you can count the number of elements using of the several methods ruby provides look up the [Array Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html) for this, and `%W` is a one of ruby niceties which allows you create an array of strings, e.g:

```
arr = %W{a b c}
arr # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

It takes almost any special character as a delimiter e.g using `.` as a delimeter

```
arr = %W.a b c.
arr # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

So in your snippet from the question `/` is delimiter used, so `s` would evaluate as below:

```
s = %W/This
is
a
test./
s # => ["This", "is", "a", "test."]
```

The above explains why the below works as it does

```
def count_lines(arr)
  arr.size
end

s = %W/This
is
a
test./
print "Number of lines: ", count_lines(s), "\n"
# >> Number of lines: 4
```